# How to vertically align to a container whose height depends on a sibling?

Tags: css

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="overlay">
      This is full width/height and absolutely positioned
   </div>
   <div id="content">
      This should be the size of #overlay MINUS the size of #second-element
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
      This has a variable height based on its own content
   </div>
</div>
```

`#content` can be easily aligned to the `#wrapper` with

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

However, is there a way to align it to `#content`? (Since its height depends on the variable `#footer`'s height)

Note: `#footer` MUST stick to the bottom of `#wrapper`, and it should not add additional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what this is supposed to look like but rather than absolute positioning, you can layer elements using CSS-Grid by assigning them the same grid location.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

#footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay,
#content {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#overlay {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 0, .5);
  width: 75vw;
  justify-self: center;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="overlay">
    This is full width/height and absolutely positioned
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    This should be the size of #overlay MINUS the size of #second-element
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    This has a variable height based on its own content
  </div>
</div>
```